# passing viewmodel correctly - changes not showing on POST

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am having trouble with my app. When the user dynamically adds rows (javascript) to add more 'claimlines' to a 'claim' the Posted values don't appear, only the 'dummy' values I initially set the ViewModel up with in the first place. So basically anything the user is amending or indeed adding (new rows) is not being recorded on POST.

As far as I can see I am passing the ViewModel between the controller and views but obviously I am missing something. I have been struggling with this for a while, your help would be hugely appreciated. Im new to ASP.NET MVC and indeed programming in general.
Im following Steven Sanderson's blog.

ViewModel

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using ef_tut.Models;
using ef_tut.ViewModels;
namespace ef_tut.ViewModels
{
    public class ClaimViewModel
    {
        public int ClaimID { get; set; }
        public int SubmissionUserID { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateSubmitted { get; set; }
        public bool ApprovedYN { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateApproved { get; set; }

        public ICollection<claimline> claimlines { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Controller

```
  using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using ef_tut.Models;
    using ef_tut.DAL;
    using ef_tut.ViewModels;
    using ef_tut.WebUI.Helpers;
    namespace ef_tut.Controllers
    {
        public class ClaimsController : Controller
        {
            private ClaimContext db = new ClaimContext();

            private static ClaimViewModel _currentclaim;
            private static ClaimViewModel Currentclaim
            {
                get
                {
                    _currentclaim = GetClaimViewModel();
                    return _currentclaim;
                }
                set
                {
                    _currentclaim = value;
                }
            }

            public static ClaimViewModel GetClaimViewModel()
            {
                return new ClaimViewModel()
            {
                ClaimID =101,
                claimlines = new List<claimline>() {
                        new claimline() {ClaimantUserID =1},
                        new claimline() {ClaimantUserID =2},
                        new claimline() {ClaimantUserID =3}
                    }
            };}

            public ActionResult Create()
            {
                return View(Currentclaim);
            }

            public PartialViewResult BlankEditorRow()
            {


                return PartialView("NewRow");
            }

            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Create(ClaimViewModel ClaimViewModel)
            {
                Currentclaim = ClaimViewModel;

                return View("View2", Currentclaim);
            }
        }
    }
```

Create View

```
@model ef_tut.ViewModels.ClaimViewModel
@using ef_tut.Models
@using ef_tut.ViewModels
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>claim</legend>
                      @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ClaimID)

        <ul id="editorRows">


                            @foreach (claimline claimline in Model.claimlines)
                            {
                                Html.RenderPartial("NewRow", claimline);
                }

        </ul> 


        <p>
               @Html.ActionLink("Add another...", "BlankEditorRow", null, new { id = "addItem" }) 

        </p>
    </fieldset>
             <input type="submit" value="Create" />



@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
}
```

Partial

```
@model ef_tut.Models.claimline

@using ef_tut.WebUI.Helpers
    @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("claims"))
    {
        <table class="editorRow">
   <tr >

                                                     <td>
            ClaimID(claimlinetable)@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ClaimID)
            </td>

       <td>
          ClaimantUserID:  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ClaimantUserID)
            </td>
                               <td>
           Hours: @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Hours)
            </td>
                                                          <td>
           <a href="#" class="deleteRow">delete</a>
            </td>
               </tr></table>
    }
```

Output view

```
@model ef_tut.ViewModels.ClaimViewModel
@using ef_tut.Models

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "View2";
}

<h2>View1</h2>

@Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.ClaimID)
    <ul>
        @foreach (claimline claimline in Model.claimlines){ 
            @claimline.ClaimantUserID; }
    </ul>
```

Comment: The `Currentclaim` property getter seems to always assign the dummy claim view model to your private variable that gets returnes.

Comment: I tried removing that reference to Currentclaim thereby just passing in the ClaimViewModel but it seems the ClaimViewModel is NULL.

Comment: Are you still seeing the 1,2,3 dummy claim lines? That would mean that code's still in use. Otherwise, what are you getting?

Comment: Yes exactly . I just can't seem to overwrite it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need use BeginCollectionItem helper with parameter collectionName equal to collection name in view model (claimlines). It's because this helper replace HtmlFieldPrefix and names generated for html fields are:
specified_collection_name[generated_index].claimline_property_name

So in your case generated names for inputs are like:
claims[generated_index].Hours

But mvc model binder can't find property claims in ClaimViewModel.

If you replace @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("claims")) with @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("claimlines")) generated input names will be like:

claimlines[generated_index].Hours

and model binder will generate ClaimViewModel as you expected